# "fazer-se de rogado" pode significar fazer-se de desentendido ou fingir ser um idiota que não entende as coisas?"

Tags: significado, expressões-idiomáticas

A dúvida a respeito de **"fazer-se de rogado"** surgiu quando eu tentava traduzir "fare l"indiano" (to feign ignorance) do italiano para o português.  Pensei que "fazer-se de rogado" poderia ser uma opção.  **No entanto, ao procurar o significado de "fazer-se de rogado" nos dicionários disponíveis, o que encontrei foi o seguinte:**

> - Gostar que lhe peçam com muito empenho; fazer-se caro. [(Piberam)](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/rogado)
> - Fingir não estar disposto a fazer algo; demorar a atender a um pedido. [(Dicionário Criativo)](http://dicionariocriativo.com.br/expressoes/mentira/mentira)
> - Não ceder a um pedido senão depois de muito instado, para valorizar a seu favor. [(Infopédia)](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/rogado)
> - Gostar que lhe peçam com muito empenho. (Aurelio Online)

Bem, o que eu sempre ouvi em pt-BR foi a expressão "não se faça de rogado" com o sentido de **"não se faça de desentendido"**.  Procurei exemplos na literatura através do Google Books e encontrei as seguintes frases que sugerem tal sentido:

> - [**Marta, Marta! Aonde é que se vê transparência aqui no Brasil? Outra coisa: Não se faça de rogada; afinal, você também é uma 'política'!**](http://www.em.com.br/app/noticia/politica/2015/01/27/interna_politica,611990/em-artigo-marta-critica-dilma-e-pt-e-diz-que-faltou-transparencia.shtml)
> - [**Que o mundo não se faça de rogado, a coalizão que é liderada pelos Estados Unidos, vai lançar mão de todos os meios bélicos para destruir ...**](http://blogdosargentotavares.blogspot.com.br/2015/12/que-o-mundo-nao-se-faca-de-rogado.html)
> - [**"Talvez o senhor possa justificar a sua presença nos arredores do pub quando ocorreu o crime."   - “Crime?”, fazendo-se de rogado o doutor.**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=Tp0sAQAAMAAJ&q=%22fazendo-se+de+rogado%22&dq=%22fazendo-se+de+rogado%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiH5bPg-aPPAhWIjpAKHcOaAz4Q6AEIQjAJ)
> - [**Não se faça de rogada. Meu pai me falou tudo.**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=9cuTLEvmDisC&pg=PA62&dq=%22n%C3%A3o+se+fa%C3%A7a+de+rogada%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwifgILt_qPPAhXFDZAKHbe3A3cQ6AEINDAE#v=onepage&q=%22n%C3%A3o%20se%20fa%C3%A7a%20de%20rogada%22&f=false)
> - [**Ah, não se faça de rogada, você sabe muuuito bem do que estou falando!**](https://fanfiction.com.br/imprimir/historia/57589/capitulo/22)

Em pt-BR, nos exemplos acima, **"rogado"** poderia facilmente ser substituído por: **idiota**, **sonso**, **cínico**, **desentendido**.  Minha pergunta então: **quais os significados possíveis e qual o mais comum para "fazer-se de rogado", tanto em Portugal quanto no Brasil?**

**Notem bem que os exemplos que encontrei são todos de sites brasileiros. Não encontrei exemplos de "fazer-se de rogado" com o sentido de "fazer-se de desentendido" em sites de Portugal.**

Comment: *Fazer-se rogado* sugere-me sempre alguém relutante a aceitar um convite ou oferta, ainda que ouça a expressão frequentemente usada em outros contextos, como nos exemplos do Artefacto. Eu diria que no teu 1º exemplo, o significado é o dos dicionários -- finge desinteresse para o outro lhe rogar que venda as terras. No penúltimo também poderá ser (não se faça de rogado = não hesite), mas não compreendi completamente (o que é um BO?). No 3º e 4º é claramente 'desentendido'.

Comment: @Jacinto  PM = Polícia Militar e BO = Boletim de Ocorrência (quando alguém vai a uma delegacia de polícia no Brasil fazer algum relato, aquilo que fica registrado é chamado de Boletim de Ocorrência.  Como será que chamam isso em Portugal?

Comment: Não faço ideia. Até pode ser a mesma coisa. Então aí também é mais próximo do significado do dicionário (não hesite).

Comment: Notem bem que os exemplos que consegui foram todos de pt-BR.  Não encontrei exemplos vindos de Portugal.

Comment: @Jacinto    Substituí os exemplos que pareciam ambíguos.

Comment: Estou um bocado perplexo. Eu encontro no Brasil de facto alguns exemplos de *não se faça de rogado* no sentido de 'não se faça de desentendido'; mas a maioria dos que encontro é no sentido de 'não hesite, não se iniba', que vem diretamente do sentido literal (não queira que lhe roguemos).

Comment: @Jacinto   Pois é, em pt-BR **escrito**, eu encontrei também que a maioria se refere ao que o Artefacto e o Eduardo descrevem.  Mas, na minha família, e no meio em que cresci, em particular, sempre foi muito comum a expressão "Não se faça de rogado!"  no sentido de "não se faça de sonso" ou "desentendido".  Por outro lado, fora da expressão "fazer-se de rogado", o adjetivo "rogado" é muito unusual no pt-BR falado.

Comment: Não encontrei *fazer-se de rogado* no Aulete. A tua definição parece ser a do Priberam.

Comment: @Jacinto   Não entendi a tua edição.  Aulete?  Revendo a postagem original e modificações posteriores, nunca mencionei o Aulete.  Dese a primeira postagem, a referência foi o Piberam.

Comment: Confusão minha: tens Aurélio, eu li Aulete. O Aurélio online reproduz o Priberam. Já o Eartlhing tinha observado isso algures. A minha edição simplesmente transformou as fontes em links

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O testemunho e exemplos do Centaurus, a que eu poderia juntar mais alguns, mostram que há comunidades que usam ***fazer-se de rogado*** com o sentido de ‘fazer-se desentendido’. E naturalmente que o podem fazer, pois não precisam para isso de autorização de ninguém. É verdade que se perdeu neste uso a ligação semântica ao significado de *rogado* e *rogar*, como observou o Artefacto. Mas o significado duma expressão existe na cabeça de quem a usa e nem sempre coincide com o que pode emergir dos significados das palavras que a compõem.

Ao que consegui apurar, este uso é exclusivamente brasileiro, e mesmo dentro do Brasil parece ser muito restrito. Quer no Google Books, quer no Google geral, mesmo restringido a busca ao Brasil, e olhando os resultados mais recentes, praticamente só se encontra o sentido tradicional de ‘relutância em aceitar uma proposta, em aceder a um rogo’, que é o único sentido que eu conheço em Portugal, e foi o único que encontrei na net da África lusófona. Ou melhor, neste ‘sentido tradicional’ estou a incluir algumas extensões. Explicam-se melhor na negativa, que é como a expressão mais aparece: *não se fazer rogado* aparece frequentemente com o significado de ‘ir em frente e não hesitar, não se inibir, não se intimidar’ ou até ‘força, não esteja com meias medidas’.

Na sentido tradicional da expressão, [***rogado*** tem o significado 2 do Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/rogado), ‘a quem se dirigem rogos’. E encontramos alguns exemplos em que a expressão é usada afirmativamente num sentido muito literal (ênfase minha em todas as citações):

> A maioria das vezes o velho **se fazia rogado** e só depois de muito instado se dispunha a contar-nos alguma coisa. 
>   [[Aristides Van-Dunen (Angola), *Estórias Antigas*, 1981.]](https://www.google.pt/search?num=50&espv=2&biw=1242&bih=580&tbm=bks&q=%22o%20velho%20se%20fazia%20rogado%22&oq=%22o%20velho%20se%20fazia%20rogado%22&gs_l=serp.3..30i10k1.4890.7530.0.8469.2.2.0.0.0.0.79.157.2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.2.155.sHx2B5aLpwI)
>
> Dona Senhora trancou-se, correu com força o ferrolho barulhento. Precisava lhe mostrar que não se brinca com uma mulher séria. E ficou a aguardar o faltoso ali, metida na cama, vagando.. moída, arrasada dos nervos. Que o relaxado quebrasse as ventas na porta fechada... Ele tinha de chamá-la, cuidadoso, e também necessitado. Queria muito o humilhar e se **fazer de rogada**.
>   [[Francisco J. C. Dantas (Brasil), *Cartilha do Silêncio*, 1997.]](https://books.google.pt/books?id=EHYtAAAAYAAJ&q=%22Queria%20muito%20o%20humilhar%20e%20se%20fazer%20de%20rogada%22&dq=%22Queria%20muito%20o%20humilhar%20e%20se%20fazer%20de%20rogada%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwia9fyNgqnPAhURnRQKHYkWCygQ6AEIHTAA)

Muito mais frequentemente se encontra a expressão na negativa. O contexto por vezes é um pedido. O sentido é que não foi preciso rogar para a pessoa aceitar:

> Pediu a Frei Dionisio pra confessá-la, pois estava em falta com Deus. Frei Dionisio **não se fez de rogado** e colocando a estola sobre os ombros, sentou-se no confessionário esperando.
>   [[Joyce Cavalcante (Brasil), *Inimigas Íntimas*, 1993.]](https://www.google.pt/search?num=50&espv=2&biw=1242&bih=580&tbm=bks&q=%22Pediu%20a%20Frei%20Dionisio%20pra%20confess%C3%A1-la%2C%20pois%20estava%20em%20falta%20com%20Deus%22&oq=%22Pediu%20a%20Frei%20Dionisio%20pra%20confess%C3%A1-la%2C%20pois%20estava%20em%20falta%20com%20Deus%22&gs_l=serp.3...11542.14190.0.14464.2.2.0.0.0.0.83.151.2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.0.0.UQAwJhMwYL8)

Talvez mais frequentemente, o contexto é um convite ou oferta, que por vezes estão apenas implícitos Neste caso também não é preciso rogar ao convidado para aceitar, e a implicação é que ele não hesitou nem se inibiu:

> — […] Quede a Dora?
>   — Tá lá dentro se aprontando. Pode entrar. Vá procurá-la. Fique à vontade — disse Valquíria, feliz.
>   Silvério foi entrando, **sem se fazer de rogado.**
>   [[Pedro Corrêa Cabral (Brasil), *Xambioá: Guerrilha no Araguaia*, 1993.]](http://xambioaguerrilha.blogspot.pt/)
>
> — Que é que tem este negro que manda mais que branco no engenho?
>   — O problema do Matias é que sempre foi muito mimado. Dom Lourenço deixou que Matias aprendesse a ler e a escrever. Dom Lourenço acabou dando corda ao negro…
>   — E o negro **não se fez de rogado.**
>   [[Álvaro Cardoso Gomes (Brasil), *Os Rios Inumeráveis*, 1997.]](https://www.google.pt/search?num=50&espv=2&biw=1242&bih=580&tbm=bks&q=%22E%20o%20negro%20n%C3%A3o%20se%20fez%20de%20rogado%22&oq=%22E%20o%20negro%20n%C3%A3o%20se%20fez%20de%20rogado%22&gs_l=serp.3...3901.6099.0.6429.2.2.0.0.0.0.106.183.1j1.2.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.0.0.9rJPCrf2YvU)
>
> Patrice Trovoada atraído pelo som do bulawé, o governante **não se fez rogado** e aproveitou a circunstância para mostrar os seus dotes físicos, e de bom dançarino.
>   [[“Primeiro-Ministro Patrice Trovoada inaugura obras sociais e dança bulawé ‘Mão no Chão’ ”, *Agência Noticiosa de S. Tomé e Príncipe*, (posterior a 2007)]](http://stp-press.st/01174.htm)

O uso da expressão tem-se alargado a contextos em que não se menciona convite nenhum ou em que um convite seria mesmo absurdo. Mas nós podemos ainda imaginar que se um convite tivesse sido feito, ele teria sido aceite sem ser necessário rogar o convidado. Na realidade o que se quer dizer é que o ‘convidado’ agiu sem inibição ou hesitação:

> Outro dia eu tava andando / E escutei no rádio uma cantiga tocar / Um troço esquisito ritmado / **Não me fiz de rogado**, puxei uma prenda [moça] pra dançar
>   [[*Doidivanas* (banda gaúcha), *Xote de Zerife*.]](https://www.vagalume.com.br/doidivanas/xote-de-xerife.html)
>
> Ao encontrar com um candidato, **não se faça de rogado**: puxe a sua listinha e vá até ele, perguntando o que ele tem a dizer a respeito de cada item. Questione.
>   [[Charbel Tauil, “Voto Valioso”, *O Fluminense*, 28-8-2016.]](http://www.ofluminense.com.br/pt-br/cidades/voto-valioso)
>
> Os campeões nacionais **não se fizeram rogados** e, num ataque bem organizado, criaram pânico na baliza de Gervásio, através de um portentoso remate de Fred, mas Gervásio respondeu com uma defesa em dois tempos.
>   [[“Moçambola – 2009”, *Jornal Desportivo de Moçambique*, 18-5-2009.]](http://desportodemocambique.blogspot.pt/2009/05/mocambola-2009-fer-beira-0-fer-maputo-0.html)

Mesmo nestes últimos exemplos é possível descortinar o sentido de *não se fazer rogado*: não foi preciso rogar à pessoa para ela agir. Já no sentido de ‘fazer-se desentendido’ isso é mais difícil. Especulei uma possível origem deste sentido. Em muitos contextos em que se usa a expressão no sentido tradicional, a relutância da pessoa em aceitar o convite ou pedido é apenas exterior, fingida portanto. E alguns falantes poderiam, por desatenção ao significado próprio de *rogado*, passar a relacionar a expressão com o fingimento e não com a relutância. Eis dois exemplos em que a relutância é fingida:

> Quem tivesse alguma perspicácia conheceria, não com grande facilidade, que o major estava há muito tempo disposto a ceder, porém que queria **fazer-se rogado**.
>   [[Manuel Antônio de Almeida (Brasil), *Memórias de um sargento de Milícias*, 1852.]](https://pt.wikisource.org/wiki/Mem%C3%B3rias_de_um_Sargento_de_Mil%C3%ADcias/XLVI)
>
> À noite, marcando o fim da semana das festas do Bonfim, havia bailes nas casas de famílias da classe média suburbana, com o pianista, “um moleque de croazê” **fazendo-se de rogado**, “fingindo má vontade”, até que a dona da casa o conduzia pelo braço ao banquinho do piano
>   [[José Ramos Tinhorão (Brasil), *Século XX*, 2010.]](https://books.google.pt/books?id=ADwIdwQMayMC&pg=PA216&dq=%22fazendo-se%20de%20rogado%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHjLyR36fPAhXIMhoKHeKKCgcQ6AEIJDAB#v=onepage&q=%22fazendo-se%20de%20rogado%22&f=false)

Noutros contextos a atitude de uma pessoa presta-se a interpretações que oscilam entre o ‘fazer-se rogado’ no sentido convencional e ‘fazer-se desentendido’, o que pode facilitar a transferência de Significado. Por exemplo, no exemplo seguinte uma mulher interpela um rapaz, e este ignora-a. Quem está de fora pode pensar que o rapaz finge não perceber que a mulher se dirige a ele — se faz de desentendido — ou que ele quer que ela insista antes de lhe dar atenção — se faz de rogado:

> Sem nada dizer, o silêncio ainda foi a minha resposta, e isso provocou mais os nervos da malfadada senhora.
>   — Ô, menino! Estou falando com você! — Bradou alto. — **Não se faça de rogado**! O que pensa que tu é? Num passa de um pobre diabo! Seu pai há de saber da tua petulância comigo! Mas onde já se viu? Um fedelho desse ignorar uma senhora de respeito como eu!
>   [[Manuel Pedro Souza Oliveira (Brasil), *Alma de Nadador*, 2014.]](https://books.google.pt/books?id=fo6PBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA51&dq=%22fa%C3%A7a%20de%20rogado%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLxPj0y6jPAhWEbhQKHVTKByEQ6AEIQTAF#v=onepage&q=%22fa%C3%A7a%20de%20rogado%22&f=false)

Comment: Mas isso é uma tese!   (risos)

Comment: Foi também o que percebi: tanto no sentido descrito nos dicionários, quanto no sentido dos exemplos que citei, a expressão é muito mais comum na negativa.  Fora da expressão, eu poucas vezes ouvi a palavra "rogado" isoladamente. O verbo "rogar", inclusive, me parece "outdated".  Em textos religiosos é onde o encontramos mais frequentemente "eu rogo a Deus", "rogai por nós", etc.

Comment: @Centaurus O meu conhecimento de *rogar* também é só passivo (exceto no sentido diferente de 'rogar pragas'). Andei a ver o uso de *fazer-se* de rogado, e depois quis dar uma ideia do leque de usos, do mais literal ao mais figurado.

Comment: "rogar pragas",  good call. That's still pretty much in use here.

Answer (score 5):

**Não**, *fazer-se rogado* não significa *fazer-se desentendido*. Significa, sim, *fazer-se (de) difícil*:

> ♦ *Fazer-se rogar*, dificultar-se em conceder o que se lhe pede; gostar que lhe peçam com insistência alguma coisa; o mesmo que *fazer-se rogado*: «… entra ele (homem) vendendo bulas, e *fazendo-se* de *rogar*, e que tem dous mil quintais para provimento do povo, que há-de ficar bramindo…» (*Grande Enciclopédia Portuguesa e Brasileira*, entrada para *rogar*)

O *Dicionário Estrutural, Estilístico e Sintáctico da Língua Portuguesa* de Énio Ramalho indica um par de significados ligeiramente diferentes, mas ainda bastante próximos:

> **fazer-se rogado**: fez-se muito rogada quando lhe pediram para cantar, mas ela estava morta por isso (só acedeu depois de  muito instada)
>
> **rogado, fazer-se**: ele era um excelente artista, mas fazia-se r. quando lhe pediam que tocasse em público (não se mostrava disposto a, procurava esquivar-se); quando o convidaram para provar a pinga na adega ele não se fez r. (não fez cerimónias, não precisou que o convidassem segunda vez)
>
> **rogado, não se fazer**: o conhecido pianista não se fazia r. quando lhe pediam para tocar em espetáculos de beneficência (estava sempre disposto a)

Admito que fazer-se de desentendido possa ser de facto uma das formas de alguém se fazer difícil, mas 1) não é a estratégia mais óbvia (que será fingir não ter interesse) e 2) mesmo que seja a estratégia usada, isso não significa que seja *fazer-se rogar* a transmitir a ideia de *fazer-se de desentendido* (terá de vir de outros elementos do contexto) — *fazer-se rogar* refere-se apenas a exibir relutância em satisfazer um pedido (no sentido mais literal, para que alguém nos "rogue" que o façamos).

Exemplos do CETEMPúblico:

> - *par=ext391547-eco-95b-4*: O Verão **fez-se rogado** e começou tarde, em termos climatéricos, e a procura ressentiu-se.
> - *par=ext313972-soc-95b-2*: Os maridos que **se fizeram rogados** ficaram sentados e as senhoras começaram a dançar umas com as outras.

Em Portugal, contudo, a expressão aparece quase sempre na negativa, onde muitas vezes o significado é já próximo de *não hesitar* (como no último exemplo):

> - *par=ext49135-clt-94a-1*: Tippin é conhecido por nunca **se fazer rogado** e chega a estar três horas a assinar autógrafos depois de um «show» extenuante.
> - *par=ext81051-des-92b-2*: Em Bucareste, ninguém **se faz rogado** para desbloquear mais fundos
> - *par=ext621309-pol-92b-2*: Sem **se fazer rogado**, o ministro da Defesa «atacava» a feijoada à brasileira com o apetite de quem não está com angústias.
> - *par=ext699640-des-98a-1*: António Costa não **se fez rogado** e mandou-o de imediato para a rua.

Comment: Acho que precisas de contextualizar o «não» inicial, porque *fazer-se de rogado* é usado e entendido como 'fazer-se desentendido' por alguns. Não sei se te referes só a Portugal; ou que o sentido de *fazer-se desentendido* não pode ser justificado pelo sentido próprio de *rogar*...

Comment: Também podias explicar melhor o teu ponto 2) (3º parágrafo). Queres dizer *fazer-se rogado* a **compreender** a ideia?

Comment: @Jacinto Onde eu quero chegar é que _fazer-se rogado_ não transmite a ideia de _fazer-se desentendido_, o que não significa que não possa alguém fazer-se rogado fazendo-se desentendido. _Fazer-se rogado_ transmite a ideia de relutância em fazer algo que se pede ou que é esperado, _fazer-se desentendido_ é apenas fingir que não se percebe qualquer coisa.

Comment: Acho que valia a pena reformulares aquilo. Eu compreendo o que tu acabaste de explicar (acrescentaria ***o sentido literal de** fazer-se rogado* não transmite...). Eu volto lá acima e não reconheço no que lá está o que explicaste aqui.

Comment: @Jacinto Já viste a edição?

Comment: Só vi agora. Finalmente compreendi a frase original.

Comment: Notem bem que os exemplos que consegui foram todos de pt-BR. Não encontrei exemplos vindos de Portugal.

Comment: @Centaurus É possível que o uso seja diferente no Brasil, mas, se o é, não o encontrei dicionarizado em lado nenhum.

Comment: Artefacto, realmente não consta nos dicionários.  Nem mesmo no Aurélio.  Mas te garanto que, certo ou errado, é usado também no sentido de desentendido no pt-BR falado.  Veja as cinco frases exemplos que postei acima. (substitui duas que pareciam ambíguas por outras mais claras.)

Comment: Gostaria que tu comentasses alguma coisa sobre esse uso no Brasil (certo ou errado, popular ou culto, constando em dicionários ou não, etc) para eu aceitar a tua resposta que, no restante, é exatamente o que perguntei.

Answer (score 2):

“Fazer-se de rogado” **pode sim** significar fazer-se de desentendido ou fingir ser um idiota porque a expressão vem da dificuldade no atender de um pedido, não da intenção.

[Rogar](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/rogar) significa "*pedir por favor*" ou suplicar.

[Rogado](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/rogado) significa "Aquele a quem se dirigem rogos ou pedidos; instado."

Faze de rogado:

> Gostar que lhe peçam com muito empenho; fazer-se caro; fazer-se
>   rogado. "rogado", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em
>   linha], 2008-2013, priberam.pt/dlpo/rogado [consultado em 23-09-2016].

Imagina uma situação em que alguém suplica: um traficante que sequestrou alguém e vai matá-lo. A vítima está desesperada, tentando convencer o traficante a não matá-la, mas aquele está decidido a fazê-lo. Muito provavelmente, os pedidos da vítima não serão atendidos porque quem ouve não deseja atendê-los por N razões.

A vítima roga e o traficante é rogado.

Note que o rogo aqui não é um simples pedido, mas algo mais profundo e daí surge a expressão fazer-se de rogado. No fundo, o que ela quer dizer, é que alguém se põe na posição de quem está a fazer um grandessíssimo favor, ou a conceder uma graça gigantesca, por um pedido simples.

Um bom sinônimo aqui seria "*fazer-se de difícil*".

Agora, se a pessoa se faz de difícil por se fazer de desentendido ou simplesmente porque não quer atender, já não está diretamente ligado à expressão "fazer de rogado".

Então "*fazer-se de rogado*" pode ser contextualizada por qualquer coisa ligada a "*fazer-se de difícil*", dependendo da situação.

- *João fazia-se de rogado, fingindo não compreender o que Robervalda queria ao pedir que lhe emprestasse o carro*.
- *João odiava sequer imaginar que Robervalda fosse encontrar-se com Gumercindo. Agora ela estava ali, implorando pelo carro e repetindo - Não se faça de rogado*.
- *João viu aqueles deliciosos chocolates na mesa de Gumercinda*.
  — *Posso*?
  — *Não se faça de rogado*.

Comment: • Gostar que lhe peçam com muito empenho; fazer-se caro; fazer-se rogado.

"rogado", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2013, http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/rogado [consultado em 23-09-2016].

Comment: Não percebi este comentário... Expica melhor. Queres que eu adicione à resposta?

Comment: Pode ser um complemento à sua resposta.

Comment: Notem bem que os exemplos que consegui foram todos de pt-BR. Não encontrei exemplos vindos de Portugal.